# How can i add like editext widget on appwidget for home screen like google search bar

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-widget

How can I allow a user to enter some information and save directly from widget?

Comment: You have to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppWidget do not support editext widget it supports only following widgets

AnalogClock
Button
Chronometer
ImageButton
ImageView
ProgressBar
TextView
ViewFlipper
ListView
GridView
StackView
AdapterViewFlipper

You can have button on textview make it look like edittext with drawable and as soon as user clicks open a transparent activity with edittext.

Comment: Is there any other way where i can do like edittext ??

Comment: look at it carefully it is not a editext it starts transparent activity with EditText when you click on it.

Comment: made changes in my answer it might help you